# Binding viewmodel to view has usercontrol with own viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a UserControl 'UserControlA' with ViewModel 'ViewModelA'.
'UserControlA' has 'UserControlB', and 'UserControlB' has 'ViewModelB'.

When I bind a DependencyProperty in 'UserControlA' with 'ViewModelA' property,
there is none of setter fired.

Belows are code,

ViewA.xaml

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyTest.ViewModel
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyTest.Views
         x:Name="userControl" x:Class="MyTest.Views.UserControlA"             
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:UserViewModel x:Name="uvModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
<custom:UserControlB></custom:UserControlB>
```

ViewA.cs

```
public partial class UserView : UserControl, IUserView
{        
    static DependencyProperty UserTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserType", typeof(UserType), typeof(UserView), new PropertyMetadata(UserType.None));
    public UserType UserType { get { return (UserType)GetValue(UserTypeProperty); } set { SetValue(UserTypeProperty, value); } }
    public ViewA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Binding typeBinding = new Binding();
        typeBinding.Source = this.DataContext;
        typeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("User.UserType");
        typeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
        this.SetBinding(UserTypeProperty, typeBinding);           
    }
```

ViewModelA.cs

```
public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{

    User user = new User();
    public User User
    {
        get { return this.user; }
        set
        {
            this.user = value;                
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => User);                
        }
    }
```

Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: There appears to be a bunch of wrong in here, but not sure if caused by editing the question down. Your DP definition is lacking getters/setters, you claim `has usercontrol with own viewmodel` yet I don't see that (horrible code smell) in your code, and I can't tell if your ViewModelA has a public property ViewModelB, which it should if your UserControlB is nested in your ViewModelA.

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry. I updated the question and add some of codes.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
typeBinding.Source = this.DataContext;
```

is redundant, because the DataContext is implicitly used as source object of the Binding.

However, during the execution of the UserControl's constructor the `DataContext` property is not yet set (i.e. it is `null`), so you are effectively setting the Binding's `Source` property to `null`. Just remove that line, or write

```
SetBinding(UserTypeProperty, new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("User.UserType"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
});
```